# MODX: I added a resource page and now all my links are broken

Tags: .htaccess, friendly-url, modx

A client wanted me to add a page to his Modx website. I am only a Joomla/Wordpress guy but I figured I would take a stab at it.

Here were my steps:

I clicked "new document", gave the page a template, a name, a parent, then pasted in some dummy text and hit save.

Now, all of my links look like this: http://www.myurl.com/modx/contact.html

*edit:  Actually that is how they are supposed to look according to google.  They just simply are not linking to the page any longer.*

My blog link still looks like this: http://www.myurl.com/blog (and it is the only link on the page that works)

I cannot delete the resource that I created under any circumstances. Modx just crosses it out in red and there is no option to permanently delete it, that I can find.

*edit: Got that part solved... :)*

Thanks for your help, I am trying to fix this before the client realizes it is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting rid of the resource group assignments sorted out the issue, and the site is now fully accessible again.

Answer (score 0):

You specified `base` tag in head? Like this: `<base href="http://www.myurl.com/modx/" >`.
And to fully remove the resource you need to press the trash icon on top resource panel tree.

Comment: I didn't touch any of the html code, I just added a new page and hit save.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know if I can't get this worked out in just a bit. (Email copied)

Comment: Ok, i delete previous comment. Write if have questions.

Comment: The Senior Developer at Modx is looking into it and is literally scratching his head. This is not good lol

Comment: The answer he gave me is posted below: